# Downloading files inside the subfolders of a Main folder in Sharepoint

Tags: python, python-requests, sharepoint-online

I am trying to download all the files within 4 (or more) sub-folders which is inside the main folder named `'Reports'` in SharePoint.

I used the following code:

```
url = 'https://HAHA.sharepoint.com/sites/Forms/Reports/'
import getpass
domain = 'HAHA.sharepoint.com' 
user = getpass.getuser() 
pwd = getpass.getpass(prompt='What is your windows AD password?')
 

import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth
from urllib.parse import unquote
from pathlib import Path

 
filename = unquote(Path(url).name)
response = requests.get(url, auth=HttpNtlmAuth(f'{domain}\\{user}', pwd ))


for file in filename:
        with open(filename, 'wb') as local_file:
            local_file.write(response.content)
```

However, I get an error:

> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'AllItems.aspx?FolderCTID=0x0120001B8F714072E1184781C4A5E4969E4CC9&id=/Reports'

Would anyone help me fix this? I'm wondering if this code is specifically downloading one file. I want to download the whole folder and its sub-folders and the files within the sub-folders.

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to following code to get files in subfolders

```
import os
import sharepy

s = sharepy.connect("https://example.sharepoint.com")
site = "https://example.sharepoint.com/sites/test"
library = "Test Library"

# Get list of all files and folders in library
files = s.get("{}/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('{}')/items?$select=FileLeafRef,FileRef"
              .format(site, library)).json()["d"]["results"]

for file in files:
    source = "https://" + s.site + file["FileRef"]
    dest = "." + file["FileRef"]
    # Check if item is file or folder
    folder = s.get("{}/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('{}')"
                   .format(site, file["FileRef"])).status_code == 200
    print(source)

    if not os.path.exists(dest):
        if folder:
            os.makedirs(dest)  # Create folders
        else:
            s.getfile(source, filename=dest)  # Download files
```